# SuppressStaticInitializationFor is it configurable at project level

Tags: powermockito

Does PowerMock Configuration file allow configuring SuppressStaticInitializationFor at project level?

Comment: You mean for all classes?

Comment: Yes at project level for all the classes for third party libraries which can have static initializations